# If From & To date is same record not filtering LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, class-library

I am filtering records based on `Dates` using `Where` clause but it's not working. *From* and *To* date is same & one record comes within the same date but that getting eliminates.

> todate {11/6/2018 12:00:00 AM}  //while debugging

```
if (toDate != "0")
{
    var todate = DateTime.Parse(toDate).Date;
    query = query.Where(x => x.CreatedDate.Date <= todate);
}
var homework = query.Select(x => new StudentHomework
{
    HomeworkId = x.HomeworkID,
    CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate
}).OrderByDescending(i => i.CreatedDate).Skip(pageLong * recordLong - recordLong).Take(recordLong);
return homework.Any()
    ? Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, homework)
    : Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
```

From db coming one record to controller while debugging in VS

[image]

But `query` is showing `0` records & in ResulView getting below messages

> Message = "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ
>   to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation
>   properties are supported.

If I remove filter in my mobile app `json` result coming like this

```
"HomeworkId": 1400,
"ClassName": "Class 1",
"SectionName": "N/A",
"SubjectName": "Mathematics",
"IsAnswered": false,
"CreatedDate": "2018-11-06T00:00:00",
```

Comment: What are the milliseconds? Possibly that they are different on two dates.

Comment: I need only date, I want to ignore time so that I am using `DateTime.Parse(toDate).Date`

Comment: Oh right. I'm not sure but it could be that calling .Date in the linq query doesn't translate correctly to the database

Comment: What database is this, what does the query translate to in sql, obviously this would be the first thing you checked right?

Comment: @TheGeneral - This is not database, This the screenshot of controller while debugging. In fact I am using SQL Server. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that there are valid records in 'query' which will satisfy the given date condition?

Comment: What type of reference is query object? Add ToList() at end. might work

Comment: Its actually unclear what you are asking, or what the results are you are getting

Comment: @TheGeneral - I am filtering Homework, selecting past dates. Both date are same _11/6/2018_ from & to. One record is created on _11/6/2018_, but in filter that is not showing up. Just getting removed by above `Where` clause.

Comment: How you are testing that expected item not included in the result?

Comment: You said that "Result has one record, while debugging controller in VS" but then result is coming up with 0 later on. Can you please show where are you using this result? if this is part of a controller may be useful to post rest of the action method up to the point where you return the actual action result

Comment: @Fabio - Debugging, after executing `query = query.Where(x => x.CreatedDate.Date <= todate);` this line `query` has 0 record.

Comment: @Sorin87bv - Result means my output of `query` particularly I am not using word result. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @CGPA6.4, after executing that line your query will not execute in the first place. Query will be executed only when you "materialize" it by calling `ToList()` or loop the results.

Comment: @Fabio - I got your point. Please look at updated question.

Comment: You do realize you are using less than or equals

Comment: @CGPA6.4 can you try by converting your date to DayOfYear, syntax will be somthing like 

 var todate = DateTime.Parse(toDate).Date;
    query = query.Where(x => x.CreatedDate.Date.DayOfYear <= todate.DayOfYear);
 
 also check if you CreatedDate and todate both are in same format (dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy)

Comment: Based on the message your filter wasn't working at all from the beginning. I hope you don't have `try .. catch` around ;)

Comment: @Fabio - I had try catch block but control was not jumping to it and was't not executing further after that line. You can check out my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all feeling stupid to wasting time of everyone by asking confusing question. Here the issue was this line's `.Date`

```
query = query.Where(x => x.CreatedDate.Date <= todate);
```

In  LINQ to Entities I should not have `.Date` and it is not allowing throwing `Exception`. After removing this everything working fine. I have `try` `catch` block but control was not jumping to it.